# R tidymodels - step_novel does not work when combined in a workflow with resampling

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am using step_novel in my workflow so that I avoid errors related to new levels in factors, however it does not appear to work in resampling as I keep getting an error regarding new levels.

Here is a reproducible code:

```
# Create sample data
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
num_samples <- 100
outcome <- rnorm(num_samples, mean = 50, sd = 10)
numeric_predictor <- rnorm(num_samples, mean = 30, sd = 5)
categorical_predictor <- as.factor(sample(letters[1:4], num_samples, replace = TRUE))

# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  Outcome = outcome,
  Numeric_Predictor = numeric_predictor,
  Categorical_Predictor = categorical_predictor
)


new_row <- data.frame(
  Outcome = 55,
  Numeric_Predictor = NA,
  Categorical_Predictor = "problem"
)

# Add the new row to the dataframe
df <- rbind(df, new_row)


lr_full_preprocessing <- 
  recipe(Outcome ~ ., data = df) %>%
  # knn-imputation 
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors(), neighbors = 1, options = list(nthread = 8, eps = 1e-08)) %>%
  # novel categories
  step_novel(all_nominal_predictors())

lr_full <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm")

lr_full_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(lr_full_preprocessing, blueprint = hardhat::default_recipe_blueprint(allow_novel_levels = TRUE)) %>%
  add_model(lr_full)

set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
folds <- vfold_cv(df, v = 10, repeats = 5)

lr_full_fit_rs <- lr_full_wf %>% 
  fit_resamples(folds)

collect_metrics(lr_full_fit_rs)
```

I get the following error

```
> lr_full_fit_rs <- lr_full_wf %>% 
+   fit_resamples(folds)
→ A | error:   factor Categorical_Predictor has new levels problem
There were issues with some computations   A: x5 <---------------------
```

After some research maybe it is related to this issue/bag https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/1249 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `lm()` doesn't handle unseen levels well. It essentially only looks at the levels it observed when fitting, even if the factor levels are different. Filed an issue here https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues/1084 in case we figure out a better way of handling this

So setting `step_novel()` by itself isn't enough. Since `lm()` will create dummy variables of the categorical predictors, you can "fix" this issue by doing that in the recipe instead.

Adding `step_dummy()` and `step_zv()` will create dummy variables and remove the zero variance predictor which in our case is the novel predictor.

```r
lr_full_preprocessing <- 
  recipe(Outcome ~ ., data = df) %>%
  # knn-imputation 
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors(), neighbors = 1, options = list(nthread = 8, eps = 1e-08)) %>%
  # novel categories
  step_novel(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())
```